# How to handle UnwrapRefSimple in Vue composition api with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings, vue-composition-api

When using reactive objects Vue composition api I get Typescript errors about `UnwrapRefSimple<T>`.
This seems specifically the case when using arrays inside `ref()`.

An example.

```js
interface Group<T> {
  name: string
  items: T[]
}

export function useSomething<T extends object>({ model }: { model: T }) {

  const groupsArray = ref([] as Group<T>[])

  const group = {
    name: 'someGroup',
    items: [model],
  }

  groupsArray.value.push(group) // <-- this line is the problem

  return {
    groups: groupsArray,
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; items: T[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; items: UnwrapRefSimple<T>[]; }'.
  Types of property 'items' are incompatible.
    Type 'T[]' is not assignable to type 'UnwrapRefSimple<T>[]'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'UnwrapRefSimple<T>'.
        Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'UnwrapRefSimple<T>'
```

I've tried things like adding `UnwrapRef` to the code:

```js
import { UnwrapRefSimple } from "@vue/composition-api"
...
items: UnwrapRefSimple<T[]>
```

But then problems pop up elsewhere in the code and besides, this becomes difficule to read.
Does anyone know how to handle this nicely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const groupsArray = ref<T[]>([]) as Ref<T[]>
```

see: https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/2136#issuecomment-908269949

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).